# Ant javascript and socket numberformatexception

Tags: javascript, ant, hudson

I have this ant target to validate if a port is being occupied. The script does in fact get the correct port of 8080, although some reason there's a new line.

```
<loadfile srcfile="hudson.xml" property="port">
            <filterchain>
                <scriptfilter language="javascript">
                if (self.getToken().indexOf("httpPort") != -1)
                    self.setToken(parseInt(self.getToken().substring((self.getToken().indexOf("httpPort")+9),(self.getToken().indexOf("httpPort")+9) + 4)));
                else
                    self.setToken(null);
                </scriptfilter>
                <ignoreblank/>
                <trim/>
            </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <echo message="Checking whether Hudson is running"/>
    <condition property="hudson.running">
      <socket server="localhost" port="${port}"/> 
    </condition>
```

This throws a Numberformatexception. I need to parse this hudson.xml file for the port and validate that it's currently not being used. Any advice?

BUILD FAILED

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$11.set(IntrospectionHelper.java:1069)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper.setAttribute(IntrospectionHelper.java:388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:349)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChild(UnknownElement.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.java:346)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:198)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:160)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more filter in the filterchain - [`stripinebreaks`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#striplinebreaks).

Your scriptfilter is replacing the whole line with just the port number found on the line, but that doesn't remove the new line at the end.